# ExtJS Align Property for Item

Tags: css, extjs, alignment

I have an item that looks like this:

```
items: [{
                xtype: 'box',
                html: '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?mychart" alt="" style="text-align:center" />',
                name: 'first',
                id: 'first',
                align:'center',
                style:
                {
                    float:'left',
                    padding: '0px 0px 10px 0px',
                },
                width:'100%'
            }]
```

I am trying to get it aligned center, I have tried putting in a custom style (underneath padding:) but it says unrecognized character in "text-align". I've also tried putting align:'center' which isn't doing anything at all, but its not causing any errors.

Last thing I did (getting desperate) I added in an inline-style for text align but the box that its inside needs the style not the actual html.

I've tried looking through the documentation and couldn't find text-align under the style doc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `text-align` without quoting it isn't valid syntax for an object literal. c.f. "[JSON syntax for property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380855/json-syntax-for-property-names/380868#380868)".

```
style: {
  ...
  text-align: 'center'
  ...
}
```

... should instead be ...

```
style: {
  ...
  "text-align": 'center'
  ...
}
```

It also sounds like you're likely to have more luck with `vertical-align` or `line-height` than `text-align`.

Comment: also, since its javascript - you can use the javascript keyword for the "text-align" attribute, which is "textAlign".

like this: `style: { textAlign : 'center' }`

Answer (score 0):

text-align only works on child elements, you have a couple of choices here:

1. Use the deprecated html properties valign="middle" and align="center", which work on the current element.
2. Put a div around the img and then put style="text-align:center", just remember that text-align only works on inline elements. (img is inline).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a css class in Main.scss file ,declare all the aligning properties in that and apply class in your component where you're using it in js file,using

```
cls:"align-Items",
```

in scss file

```
.align-Items{
 vertical-align: top;
}
```