# JSON and javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json

```
var foo = { "a": 1, "b": true, c: [1, true, "2"] };
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong here, but as far as I know, this is a valid json object. But it's also a javascript object.

Are JSON objects based on the javascript language? Or is it the other way around?

Thanks

Comment: `JSON` means JavaScript Object Notation. That should pretty much answer your question, and also imply what came first.

Comment: Google is your friend. A simple guide: http://docs.1060.org/docs/3.1.0/book/discovered/doc_mod_json_guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Please correct me if I'm wrong here, but as far as I know, this is a valid json object"

No.

"But it's also a javascript object."

yes.

UPDATE: my original answer continues below, but I missed an important syntax error which is helpfully pointed out by @badunk

The string

```
{ "a": 1, "b": true, c: [1, true, "2"] }
```

is JSON. JSON is just about *notation* - about which symbols make up valid syntax, and what they mean if they are processed.

Your code:

```
var foo = { "a": 1, "b": true, c: [1, true, "2"] };
```

..is a piece of javascript. When this is parsed and processed, the part on the right side of the assignment is called a javascript object literal. That is, a piece of javascript that denotes a literal object. But because it is in fact an object, it is not notation anymore - it is processed into a runtime data structure.

The term JSON is useful when you're talking about data exchange, for instance over HTTP. If a HTTP response passes a sting like this:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": true, c: [1, true, "2"] }
```

it is valid JSON. 
If that would be interpreted, it would result in a javascript object.

Answer (score 4):

> Are JSON objects based on the javascript language?

Yes.

See [the specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a lightweight, text-based, language-independent data interchange format.  It was derived from the ECMAScript Programming Language Standard.

Note that ECMAScript is the [standardised version of JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript).

Answer (score 1):

from the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) website

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language.

So the answer to your question will be yes.

Answer (score 1):

One can argue that there's no such thing as a "JSON object" (http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Your code, above, is in fact an object literal. JSON, on the other hand, is just a string representation of an object, i.e. it's a serialisation.

Answer (score 1):

as @Roland pointed out, the statement itself is a javascript expression, not JSON.  Ignoring that, however, and evaluating whether the following is JSON:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": true, c: [1, true, "2"] }
```

I disagree with the other answers here, this is not valid JSON.  Strictly speaking, properties must be enclosed in quotes.  See the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380855/json-syntax-for-property-names).  This is correct JSON:

```
{ "a": 1, "b": true, "c": [1, true, "2"] }
```

Comment: And right you are. I missed that.