# Pushing json into array for Flot Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm trying to get data into an array. The current temp array looks like this:

```
tmp[0][0] = "NY"
tmp[0][1] = "52"
tmp[1][0] = "FL"
tmp[1][1] = "25"
```

What i'm trying to do is push the data into a new array named data. The final structure for data should look like this:

```
data = [
  { label: "NY",  data: 52},
  { label: "FL",  data: 25},
]];
```

I can't seem to get that going. Here's what i tried:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    data<%=r1%>.push([label: tmp[i][0],  data: tmp[i][1]]);
}
```

all i'm hitting is brick walls and my brain hurts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your square brackets would push an array not an object, so replace the square brackets with curly brackets, like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    data<%=r1%>.push({label: tmp[i][0], data: tmp[i][1]});
}
```

Comment: thanks i changed my answer, I was thinking in json and now I have learned the diff! totally valid without the quotes.. as elaborated here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/381151/471339

Comment: Sweet... How do i iterate through the data array now?

Comment: Use the same way but now your data array contains objects. data[i].label or data[i].data

Comment: for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   alert(data[i].label);   
}

Answer (score 2):

`<%=r1%>` is an ASP tag? Do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    data<%=r1%>.push({label: tmp[i][0],  data: tmp[i][1]});
}
```

Now your data contains objects, so you can access them in this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].label);
    console.log(data[i].data);
}
```

Comment: yea... that's an ASP tag

Comment: Just use brackets instead of []